# how can I fix my outgoing email settings (smtp) in my website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I recently created a website and for some reason the submit form is not working in my webserver hostgator. It works in my localhost but it does not work in the webserver. I tried using the webserver email but it now gives me a "the operation has time out" error.

[Email Connection Settings](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/email-connection-settings)
 I tried doing what they publish but it still not working.

This is my code:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid) { return View(); }


 

        //send email to us in order to know that the user has requested 
        try {

            string email = "jose@neworiginconstruction.com";
            string password = ""; // I am using the same password to login the webmail.


            //Message 
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress(email);
           // mail.To.Add("neworiginc.inc@gmail.com");
           mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("neworiginc.inc@gmail.com"));
            mail.Subject = "You have received a new Project Request from Website";
            //mail.CC.Add("Website Conct us");

            // Body of the email
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string content = "Name: " + "<br/>";
            content += "Address: ";

            mail.Body = content;


            //Create the Smtp client system
            SmtpClient smpt = new SmtpClient();

            //host
            smpt.Host = "neworiginconstruction.com";
            
            //port 

            smpt.Port = 465;

            smpt.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

            smpt.EnableSsl = true;


            //Network credential to access your mail

            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(email, password);

            //now pass nc to smpt server

            smpt.Credentials = nc;
            smpt.Send(mail);



            ViewBag.Message = "Thank you for contacting New Origin Construction. We'll get back to you within 24 hours.";
            ModelState.Clear();
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {

            ViewBag.Message = ex.Message.ToString();
        }


         
        return View();
```

Comment: When I tested in smtp test tool website it works immediately. When I run it in my web server it is very slow.  As I mentioned it gives me a "the operation has time out" error message.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can sent email successfully in local, it means there is no code issue. Then we need to check the firewall settings. And you deployed your site to the could platform, we could check the port settings like below.

You need to [Opening an outbound port in your `HG Firewall Plugin`](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/hg-firewall-plugin#outbound).

[image]

Comment: I have tried opening the port but I cannot find that page in my control panel. My control panel is Plesk and it does not give me the option to open a port. Do you know how I can open it in Plesk.

Comment: Hi @NOC, [you can refer the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76514012/7687666), and do some research about how to add network acl in Plesk.