# Timeout when connecting to SMTP server from aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, mailkit

I am developing a .net core application that connects to smtp server to send an email. I am using MailKit to connect and send email.

This is what my code looks like

```
await client.ConnectAsync(smtpSettings.OutgoingServer, smtpSettings.Port, true);

await client.AuthenticateAsync("user@email.com", "myPassword");

await client.SendAsync(message);
```

An exception is thrown when the service is trying to connect. Here is the exception

```
Exception: System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at MailKit.Net.SocketUtils.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, IPEndPoint localEndPoint, Int32 timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MailKit.MailService.ConnectNetworkAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, SecureSocketOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at integration_communication_service_api.Helpers.Email.EmailingService.SendBasicEmail(EmailRequest emailRequest, SmtpSettings smtpSettings) in /src/integration-communication-service-api/Helpers/Email/EmailingService.cs:line 42
   at integration_communication_service_api.Handlers.EmailHandler._handle(EmailRequest request) in /src/integration-communication-service-api/Handlers/EmailHandler.cs:line 88
   at ActiveMQ.MessageHandler`1.Handle(T request) in /src/Providers/ActiveMQ/MessageHandler.cs:line 23
   at integration_communication_service_api.Controllers.EmailController.SendEmailAsync(EmailRequest emailRequest) in /src/integration-communication-service-api/Controllers/EmailController.cs:line 43
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
InnerException:
```

I only get then when the code runs on aws. Locally, it runs fine. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It could be a network configuration issue, for example if you have your service running in a private subnet without a route to a NAT Gateway, or in a public subnet without a public IP assigned to the service. Or it could be that you are using the default SMTP port 25, which AWS generally blocks by default just to keep email spammers from taking advantage of AWS. You would need to include much more details in your question if you want someone to be able to provide you with a definitive answer. To start, what is the value of `smtpSettings.Port`?

Comment: I don't have the subscription in amazon, but the issue is related to port being blocked in aws, you can [check the link to fix the issue](https://bobcares.com/blog/aws-port-25-block/) .

Comment: The port number i am using is 465 (SSL) @MarkB

Comment: Does the link useful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to resolve this issue. This is for someone who encounters the same problem.
So even though my security group was set to allow outgoing request on SMTPs port, the Network ACL was not configured to allows such outbound traffic.
To resolve the problem I need to add one new rule to the list of outbound rules for my Network ACL.
Basically the rule was to allows traffice (TCP) on port 465 to [smtp server ip address]